# run kubectl from nodejs child_proccess

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, terminal, child-process

I'm trying to run kubectl commands from NodeJs `child_proccess.exec` .
 and i'm getting the following error: `stderr: error: timed out waiting for the condition`

Here is my code

```js
import childp from 'child_process';
import util from 'util';

const exec = util.promisify(childp.exec);

(async () => {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('kubectl port-forward -n qa svc/payment-service 4008');
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.log('stderr:', stderr);
})();
```

the error appears after 60 second, (before the error the port-forward works , but nothing in output)

Comment: Just a wild guess - some sub commands might rely on a tty, you can try running it via `node-pty`.

Comment: Can you use the [Kubernetes Javascript client library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript) instead?  It even has [an example of doing port forwarding](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/typescript/port-forward/port-forward.ts).  (In general, prefer using API libraries to calling shell commands when given a choice.)